# Remove Static Text and Text Field when Field Value is null JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I know about isBlankWhenNull, but this doesn't suffice for my problem.

I have multiple text fields, each containing a field value. Each of these text fields has a static text label. I only want to print the pairs that do not have a null value and I want to avoid the blank space inbetween.

Static Text:     Text Field($F{exampleField})

So, if:

Name:     null
Age:        50
Location: null
Zip:          12345

I want:

Age:      50
Zip:       12345

Instead of:

<Blank line>
Age:      50
<Blank line>
Zip:       12345

Is there any way to do this in jasper reports? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if anyone is interested.

1. Move all the static text and text fields into a new frame element
2. Check the remove line when blank option for every element in the frame
3. Set every element's position type to "float"
4. Add print when expression "$F{fieldName} != null" to each respective static text and text field